# Need to NOT activate .blur() on input if clicking on a certain element

Tags: jquery

I've been writing my own auto-suggest, instead of it just filling in the form input it actually produces a HTML list of links and pictures which it gets straight from the AJAX request. One problem I have ran into is that I need to hide the produced list if the input loses focus, but this also happens if you attempt to click a link inside the produced list and it disappears without registering the click.

Here is my code:

```
var delay = false;
var landing = $('#suggestions');
$('#suggest').keyup(function(e) {   
    if (e.keyCode > 40 || e.keyCode == 8) { //If a letter or backspace
        if(this.value.length >= 3) { // if > 3 characters in the input
            $(this).addClass('loading');
            clearTimeout(delay);
            var query = this.value;
            delay = setTimeout( function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/response.php', //returns HTML
                    type: 'get',
                    data: { 'q' : query },
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#suggest').removeClass('loading');
                        landing.show().html(data);
                    }
                });
            }, 200);

        } else {
            landing.empty();
        }
    }

})

.focus(function() {
    if($(this).val() == 'Search...') {
        $(this).val('');
    }

    if($(this).length) {
        landing.show();
    }
})

.blur(function() {
    if(this.value.length) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            landing.hide();
        }, 150)
    } else {
        $(this).val('Search...');
    }
})

.attr('autocomplete', 'off');
```

The .blur() is where the problem is being caused, I attempted to add a timeout but this has proven to be quite unreliable.

Additionally, any comments/suggestions to improve what I written so far would be appreciated!

After lots of experimenting the best solution I have came up with is toggle a 'persist' variable on the `#suggestions` landing `<div>`, so the `blur()`` will do nothing if the user is doing something on the #suggestions box:

```
$('#suggest').blur(function() {
    if(this.value.length) {
        if(landingPersist == false) {
            landing.hide();
        }
    } else {
        $(this).val('Search Knowledge Base');
    }
})

$('#suggestions').mouseover( function() {
    landingPersist = true;
})

.mouseout(function(){
    landingPersist = false;
});
```

This method requires no live() or timers which I think is a good thing.
With a check for the persist variable in the `blur()` of `#suggest`. This met

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add global varible (outside any function) like this:

```
var _hideLandingTimer = 0;
```

Second, change the code in the `blur`:

```
_hideLandingTimer  = setTimeout(function() {
            landing.hide();
        }, 150);
```

And finally have this:

```
$('#suggest a').click(function() {
   window.clearTimeout(_hideLandingTimer);
});
```

This will clear the timer (thus not hide the landing) in case link is clicked,

Comment: I'd have to use `live()` for one thing, I also tried mousedown instead of click but the suggestions box still disappears if you hold down for a split second or right click.

Comment: Getting closer but as soon as I click a link the blur() triggers and restarts the timer

Comment: @Dun simply bind both click and mouseover then.. simple test case proves the concept itself is working: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/Vx3Fs/

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! I have came up with another solution that doesn't involve timers, I am toggling a 'landingPersist' variable on mouseover/mouseout and the blur will not doing anything if the mouse is over the #suggestions box. Only side effect is if they right-click and then don't do anything the box will persist again until they activate the blur() on #suggest. Thanks very much for your help and suggestions I will mark this as the answer!

Comment: @Dun cheers for finding better solution and thanks for the kindness! :-)